# Почему не работает функция file_get_contents ()?

Tags: php, php.ini

Какие параметры в настройках php необходимы чтобы заработала функция `file_get_contents()`. Есть два хостинга, на одном из них скрипт работает, на другом нет! При этом на хостинге, где он не работает, в настройках php указан параметр  `php_flag arllow_url_fopen 1`
Не понятно, какие еще настройки необходимы чтобы функция заработала? Скриншот информации по `phpinfo()` -  [ссылка](http://joxi.ru/p2764gEF00OoYm)

**PHP код:**

```
$usr = 'data-user.json';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал обратиться в тех поддержку хостинга, где не работает и уточнить вопрос. Возможно они на каком-либо уровне это обрубают.

Comment: а путь указывать не пробовали?

Comment: Вы, походу, перепутали переменные `$usr` и `$url`.

Comment: Возможно стоит покопать в сторону наличия файла crossdomain.xml в корне сайта откуда пробуете открыть файл..

Answer (score 1):

если **$url** содержит именно то, что ожидается и там реальная полная ссылка содержится, то первый очевидный вариант -
**у хостера закрыты исходящие подключения.**

Я встречал еще более суровое - разрешен только 80 порт, без разницы исходящий или входящий. Если по случайности исходящее соединение будет висеть на 80 порту, то оно пролезает.

Второй вариант - а проверить, ручками через curl, из консоли, вообще **работает ли запрос $url**, только не забываем скачать curl под любимую операционную систему:

```
curl -v http://чего_надо_
```

Следствие из этого варианта - со стороны сервера требуется определенный заголовок. Если броузер успешно запрашивает, предлагаю использовать хром, инструменты разработчика. вкладка "Network" и там можно правым кликом по нужному запросу выбрать "копировать как curl".

Если так заработает, придётся уйти от file_get_contents() и открыть справку по curl в php.

[отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212293/mimicking-an-ajax-call-with-curl-php) пример. Ключевая строка - про "**X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest**"

```
$postVariables = json_encode(array('productsType' => $productsType, 'historyPageIndex' => 1, 'displayPeriod' => 0));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", "__RequestVerificationToken: $token"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVariables);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.domain.com/ajax/getProductList');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.domain.com/Applications/ViewProducts');
```